# How to mark all entries for particular feed as read in newsticker?

Tags: key-bindings

I've got bunch of rss feeds in newsticker and it's nearly perfect but poorly documented. Sometimes people reinstall their blog software (wordpress is particular pile of crap in this regard) and as a result all the entries in their feed become "new". I'm pretty sure there got to be some magic key combo in newsticker to mark entire feed read again, but was unable to find it so far. Ideally I'd like to mark all the entries which are older than (year, month whatever) automatically read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the newsticker treeview, the keybind is `O`, bound to `newsticker-treeview-mark-list-items-old`.